# Java number format exception error in number systems code

Tags: java, arrays, hex, decimal

I'm doing a java number converter and whenever I try my hexadecimal to decimal converter it always gives me a `java.lang.NumberFormatException` for whatever I type that I want to convert. The console displays this error whenever I type in a string value for example ABC. How would I go about fixing this error? The error occurs at this line: `int intNum = Integer.valueOf(numHexadecimal);` in the code.

```
public static void hexToDecimal() {

        System.out.println("Enter your hexadecimal number");
        numHexadecimal = input.next();
        hexArray = numHexadecimal.toCharArray();

            int intNum = Integer.valueOf(numHexadecimal);

            int counter = 0;

            String hexVal = "";

            int digit;

            digit = intNum % 16;

            switch (digit) {
            case 1:
                hexVal+="F"; break;
            case 2:
                hexVal+="E"; break;
            case 3:
                hexVal+="D"; break;
            case 4:
                hexVal+="C"; break;
            case 5:
                hexVal+="B"; break;
            case 6:
                hexVal+="A"; break;
            default:
                hexVal+=Integer.toString(digit);          
            }

            intNum = intNum/16;

            for (counter = hexVal.length()-1; counter >= 0; counter--)
                System.out.print(hexVal.charAt(counter));

        }

    }
```

Comment: It's important to include the line that the error occurs on

Answer (score 3):

If you want to parse hexadecimal numbers you have to use [the two-parameters version of `valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(java.lang.String,int)), specifying the radix (16 for hexadecimal) as the second parameter

```
int intNum = Integer.valueOf(numHexadecimal, 16);
```